# Highchart long dataLabels and style width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

If we had long dataLabel in a pie chart and we set the style width to 100px (in order to don't have a mini pie) some dataLabel just disappear, e.g. see the value **Others1**.

How to solve this?

http://jsfiddle.net/htwh3rdh/4/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b style="width: 100px; display: block;">{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        width: '100px',
                    },
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       40],
                ['Safari veryveryveryvery long label',    8.5],
                ['Opera veryveryveryvery long label',     6.2],
                ['Others veryveryveryvery long label',   0.7],
                ['Safari1 veryveryveryvery long label',    2.5],
                ['Opera1 veryveryveryvery long label',     3.2],
                ['Others1 veryveryveryvery long label',   0.6]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: You can set useHTML flag as true for datalabels.  http://jsfiddle.net/htwh3rdh/3/

Comment: Have you tried using a JS unction that converts the dataLabel with something like '100 first characters + '...' ? Use it with `formatter`

Comment: @SebastianBochan thanks, I was as well thinking of something like this but doesn't work all the time if had more value it will get broken again http://jsfiddle.net/htwh3rdh/7/

Comment: Physically, there is not enouh space, so try to adapt [size param](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size)

Answer (score -1):

In these cases (in my experience) (with long names and small graphics) would be better to use a pie chart with a legend of this type. In this way you don't have problems with the display of names.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/46Lr9w2d/1/)

```
$(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Build the chart
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    ['Firefox iuyguiygiuygiuygiuy uygiuygiuyg',   45.0],
                    ['IE',       26.8],
                    {
                        name: 'Chrome uygiuygiuyg ',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Safariiuyg iuygiuyg',    8.5],
                    ['Opera uiy giu y giuy',     6.2],
                    ['Others iuygiuygiuyg',   0.7]
                ]
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: But my boss want dataLabel :-/ Thanks anyway

Comment: and if you set the property dataLabels (dataLabels = false) and the property showInLegend (showInLegend = true) only in the case of a screen size "small"?

Comment: The size is everytime the same, it's for PDF generated with phantomjs

Comment: (commented in the wrong place, I wanted to comment on the question)